# ext4 Specifications?

Tags: ext3, ext4

Where can I find the ext4 file system specifications?

(Unofficial drafts are fine, so long as they're reasonably up-to-date; if unavailable, ext3 would be fine too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using [ext4 Disk Layout @ kernel.org](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout). Requires careful reading and some extra research on subjects but for the most part it is complete.